# How to Create a WCF Service with 100% Availability Even Upon Update?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service

I need to create a service that will expose data and contain business logic that different clients will use.

The problem is that if I develop it as a single WCF service I will need to shutdown it for some time to update it. This is not acceptable.

I was thinking of creating core WCF service that will be watching a directory with plugins and load them dynamically if the file changes. Is this the correct way of doing this? And do I organize such system with WCF?

Comment: 100% is **literally** not achievable. Google, Amazon and Facebook can't do 100%. They have more budget than you. Decide how many 9s you need (99.9%? 99.99%? 99.99999%? do the math in minutes/year). Each extra 9 makes it much more expensive.

Comment: How much time does it take to `shutdown-copy-startup`?

Comment: How much downtime is acceptable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is load balancing acceptable to you? Then  you can have two servers and update them one at a time. There would be no interruption, and no need for a complex plugin architecture.

Comment: I agree 100%.  Add hardware rather than add complexity that will increase maintenance and the likelihood of errors.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple instances on Azure would be an easy (though perhaps not cost effective?) way of achieving this.

It would update one instance at a time with no down time between. And with >1 instance you get 99.9% uptime in the [SLA](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/sla/)

Answer (score 2):

Host it in IIS (a normal web application). On update, if you copy your new dlls to the 'bin' directory, the application will be recycled. Practically without downtime.